# How to update my mysql database using if condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my DB. The first table will be used to store the invoice details and the second one was used to store the invoices items based on invoice id.

```
<html>
<body>
<p>1.Table 1 Invocies</p>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>ID</td><td>Customer Id</td><td>Amount</td><td>Date</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1500</td><td>2014-08-05</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>500</td><td>2014-08-05</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>500</td><td>2014-08-05</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>600</td><td>2014-08-05</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>700</td><td>2014-08-05</td></tr>
</table>
<p>1.Table 2 Items</p>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>ID</td><td>ProductId</td><td>Price</td><td>Invoice Id</td><td>Quantity</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>800</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>800</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>500</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>500</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>600</td><td>4</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

With invoice Id 1 we have two products and the sum of the quantity & Price=1600 but in table 1 the amount was 1500. I want to update the all table 1 amount value is equal to sum of the quantity & price of the product based on their Invoice Id. How to write query for this?

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag because the question is explicitly about MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Amount = (SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.InvoiceID);
```

Comment: UPDATE Table1 SET Amount = (SELECT SUM(Quantity*Price) FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.InvoiceID); // this vl works fine